# UITextField not updating setText

Tags: ios, uitextfield, settext

I know there are alot of questions about this problem, but I've read everyone of them and I still have the problem, In everyother question the solution was adding a property or if the one asking just forgot to link it to the ViewController. I have done all of that and it still won't update!

my .h:

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

-(void)setCoords:(NSString *)coordinates tag:(int)tag;
```

.m

```
@synthesize textField;
```

The function that sets the text called while switching from another view:

```
-(void)setCoords:(NSString *)coordinates tag:(int)tag {
    NSLog(@"1 %@", textField);
    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,206,30)];
    NSLog(@"2 %@", textField);
    if (tag == 0) {
       [textField setText:coordinates];
       [self.view addSubview:textField];
       NSLog(@"3 %@", textField);
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", textField.text);
}
```

The `output` from the `NSLog` is always `NULL` but if I `NSLog` the string `coordinates` only I get the string.

Is there something I'm missing/not knowing/or doing wrong?

*UPDATE* UPDATED THE FUNCTION

```
NSLog 1 loggs NULL
NSLog 2 loggs <UITextField> 0x855b300; frame: = (0 0; 206 30) and some more stuff.
NSLog 3 loggs same as log 2
```

Comment: not sure but why a parenthesis in `(coordinates)` ?

Comment: My mistake while writing this question, I didnt copy paste it because Im not on my Mac atm.

Comment: In the updated code if log 3 prints then the final log must match the first or your app has got memory corruption problems.

Comment: Create a demo project showing the bug, offer a 25 pt bounty, and post it to a public place. This will surely result in a code fix.

Answer (score 0):

Your  `if (tag == 0) [textField setText:(coordinates)];` line in not getting excecuted.

Check for the `tag==0` condition, if must not be validating to true.

Answer (score 0):

First log the text field (it may be nil). Then log the text field's tag, finally log the coordinate string. Run again. Now you know the problem.

Comment: I added this to the start of the function "textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];" and now the textField.text is working, but how do I make it visible in the textfield? If i log textfield.text the sting coordinates is logged but the textField doensnt show the string.

Comment: That is not the proper designated initializer. You need to create it using initWithFrame then add it to your views subview array.

Comment: I have initWithFrame and added it with [self.view addSubview:textField]; but its still not working I alloocated with frame before the if statement and I add it to subView after the setText.

Comment: This is not normal. Create it, add it, then set the text. Log everything before and after, then update your question with the output if it's still not working.

Comment: I tried adding it before the if statement and after the alloc and it didnt not work either. I really dont know whats going on :S

Comment: Slow down. You obviously are doing something wrong. As a test do all this in viewDidLoad. It had better all work there, or your whole computer environment is hosed. Once you have this working in one place you can slowly get it working elsewhere.

Comment: I have tried it in the viewDidLoad to setText to a string and it works. The function is getting called from a completition block from another viewController after switching views.

Comment: On the main thread? Log everything - some variable is not what you think it is. I often use asserts to verify some method invocation is on the main thread.

Comment: When I first start the app when I try setText on viewDidLoad it works, but after I switch views and back again it does not work Ive allocated it and added it to subView.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in which my UITextView was created in Interface Builder. Everything was hooked up correctly, and I made sure I NSLogged values to make sure they showed up.

Two things to check:

1. Make sure your text color is NOT set to clear! (test with placeholder text)
2. You MUST in Interface Builder set the checkmark ON for "Selectable" text. If you don't want it selectable, you have to change it to OFF programatically AFTER you set the text value.

My issue was #2. This is definitely an XCode bug, but I'm glad I solved it without going too nuts.